# react redux, Action from .then not dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to fetch props into my `componentDidUpdate` method.
Sadly second action from `.then` block doesn't dispatch.

I have the following:

My `AddPerson.js` which is a form to add Person. There I have following states:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        firstName: '',
        secondName: '',
        email: '',
        date: '',
    };
}
```

Whole is connected to redux:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addPerson: data => dispatch(addPerson(data))
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { data: state.data };
};

const Person = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddPerson);

export default Person;
```

Then I have action dispatcher like that:

```
export const addPerson = (payload) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(addTodoStarted());
        axios
            .post(PATH + '/attendant', {
                payload,
            })
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(addTodoSuccess(res));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(addTodoFailure(err));
            });
    };

};

const addTodoSuccess = payload => ({
    type: ADD_PERSON,
    data: {
        payload
    }
});

const addTodoStarted = () => ({
    type: ADD_PERSON,
    data:
        "loading"

});

const addTodoFailure = error => ({
    type: ADD_PERSON,
    data: {
        error
    }
});
```

And my reducer:

```
function reducer(state = {} , action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PERSON:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                data: action.data,
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

When fetch happens in the action, there is firstly dispatched type of action `loading` then after promise solves I want to dispatch action that is in .then block. What am I missing?

> EDIT:

My componentDidUpdate looks like that:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(prevProps)
    if (prevProps.data !== this.state.data) {
        console.log(prevProps.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying that `dispatch(addTodoSuccess(res));` doesnt update the state?

Comment: Hmm apparently it do update state, I'm now seeing that after initial dispatch second one is dispatched too, but it's not triggering componentDidUpdate totally... do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: could you edit the question with the componentDidUpdate code?

Comment: Added the edit, by the way, its a dumb to ask but Im not sure, that state I did define in ```mapStateToProps``` should be also a state of the class, added in this.state = {}?

Comment: try comparing the previous props with the props. if (prevProps.data !==  this.props.data){  console.log(prevProps.data) }

Comment: Oh god that's the thing... thanks man!